# why can't turn on that AirPlay screen from within my app?

Tags: objective-c, airplay

if i  turn on that AirPlay screen from The drop-down menu，it works.

but if i turn on that AirPlay screen from within my app by

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];

 volumeView.showsRouteButton = YES;
 volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = NO;
[volumeView sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:volumeView];
```

it will crash my AirServer in my MacBook.

what should i do if i want to turn on Airplay within my app.

Comment: code can show RoutButton, but when i touch the button, my AirServer in mac flash one black window and shut up soon.

Comment: i do it ! my Airserver is wrong.i change toreflector,it success!